# What is the equivalent class for DBCursor in mongo-java 3.x?

Tags: java, mongodb

I could see the class DBCursor is deprecated in latest versions of java-mongo driver. So what is the  equivalent class for the DBCursor in the latest mongo-java driver

Answer (score 0):

DBCursor class is not deprecated, but some of the methods are. You can see a list of deprecated classes, methods, etc. in this link.

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/deprecated-list.html